# Validate mass action column

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, validation, massaction

I am using  Magento ver. 2.1.7 CE .

I added new button "Validate" in UI component layout as follows

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">          
<item name="print" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="name" xsi:type="string">print</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Validate</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/save</item>
</item>
<item name="add" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New</item>
    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/add</item>
</item></item>
```

I want to validate the checkbox for limit the selection not more than two items before submission.

If more than two selection, show popup message to user.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing validate button you can validate records in mass action file.I think it is better option because if user forgot to click on validate and direct click on mass action then all selected record operation will be performed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ya it not only perform validate, also do some function after validation...I just put sample button to explain. I want do mass selection function using button in above grid

Comment: create a custom js and manage click event of that button

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom js in view->web->js->customname.js

```
require([
    "jquery",
    "customname"
    ], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#buttonid").click(function()
            {

                $(".admin__form-field-control .admin__control-select").val(this.id);        
                //call ajax here
            });

   });
```

in js file handle click event and get id of selected row
and lastly include this js file in head section of your xml file